# Button will not work for web Cookie Clicker game

Tags: javascript, html, css

about a week or two ago I posted a (pretty noob) question about if statements for my biscuit clicker game. I have now gone through the course my school gave me and feel much more confident about asking questions on here. I am trying to add an auto clicker, but without much luck, I saw a tutorial but it was way too advanced for me (as he was using id's and some DOM stuff I don't understand) but I'm pretty sure it's possible with my knowledge. Basically, with this code, I am trying to make it so when you click the button the variable auto click goes up by one, and then there is an if statement saying if auto click is greater than 0, then run the auto() function. Then the auto function needs to +1 to bikkie (the var for biscuits) every second, but when you click the button nothing happens. (I also need help making the function run every second). Sorry if this was really long, hope someone can help!

HTML:

```
<html>

    <head>
<title>Biscuit Clicker</title>  
</head>

    <body background="background.png">
<center>  <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <big> <h1>Biscuit Clicker</h1> </big>  
<h2><span>0</span> Biscuits</h2>
 <img src="anzac_s.png" width=335px height=300px onClick="count()" onmouseenter="anim()" onmouseleave=minus() alt="Anzac Biscuit" >

</center> 

    <center> <br> <br> <button onClick="addclick()">Buy One Autoclicker</button><br> <button  onClick="save()">Save</button>  <button  onClick="load()">Load</button> <br> 
       </center> 

<script src="count.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="urmum.css">
```

JS:

```
let bikkie = 0;

let cookieimg = document.querySelector("img")
let autoclick = 0

function count() {
bikkie++;
let sprincount = document.querySelector('span');
    sprincount.textContent = bikkie;

    if (bikkie == 51)  
    alert("Good Job on getting 50 Biscuits!") 

if (bikkie == 101)  
    alert("100? GG") 

if (bikkie == 201)
    alert("good job on 200")

if (bikkie == 301)
    alert("0w0")

if (bikkie == 401)
    alert("gg")

if (bikkie == 501)
    alert("iraq, iran")

if (bikkie == 601)
    alert("0W0")
}



function auto(){
bikkie++
}

function addclick() {
    autoclick + 1
  }

if (autoclick > 0) {
    auto()
}

function save() {
localStorage.setItem("bikkie", bikkie);
  confirm("Are you sure? This will overide all other saves")  
}



function load() {
 let sprincount = document.querySelector('span')
    bikkie = localStorage.getItem("bikkie");
bikkie = parseInt(bikkie);
    sprincount.textContent = bikkie;

}


function anim() {
    cookieimg.style.transform = 'scale(1.2)';

    }

function minus() {
  cookieimg.style.transform = 'scale(1)';


}
```

CSS:

```
img {
   transition: transform 1s 
}

h1 {
   font-family: Comic Sans MS 

}

h2 {
   font-family: Comic Sans MS 

}
```

Also sorry if this code is really messy/noobish, I'm just starting out.

Comment: What do you mean by `auto clicker` ? What does this game do ? What is the stopping condition of the game ? What is the intended result ?

Comment: @ths, sorry for not being clear, I want the biscuit count (so the variable bikkies) to go up 1 every second when the Get an Autoclicker button is pressed.

Comment: when we stop adding 1 to it ?

Comment: we don't, it keeps going, it only stops when the webpage is closed.